# Gatling - correlating a json response (and modifying it in session)

Tags: json, traversal, gatling

I do one request and get a response body.
I want to use this response body in the next request, but need to add an json node before doing so.
Request 1 => Response 1:

```
 {
  "resourceType": "Parameters",
  "parameter": [
    {
      "name": "medication",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Bundle",
        "id": "08eb0474-23a2-429b-93b2-ba38b96271ec",
        "meta": {
          "lastUpdated": "2021-01-18T16:18:22.4474168+00:00",
          "source": "http://base-fhir.qa.forskrivning.no/Patient/$getMedication",
          "profile": [
            "http://ehelse.no/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-MedicationBundle"
          ]
        },
        "type": "document",
        "timestamp": "2021-01-18T16:18:22.4473963+00:00",
        "total": 27,
        "link": [
          {
            "relation": "self",
            "url": "http://base-fhir.qa.forskrivning.no/Patient/$getMedication"
          }
        ],
        "entry": [
          {
            "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:8d3fd453-2933-4f39-9c90-4df868080f40",
            "resource": {
              "resourceType": "Composition",
              "id": "a79f08c0-0b3c-4e26-adf4-6fc5d1305b36",
              "meta": {
                "profile": [
                  "http://ehelse.no/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-MedicationComposition"
                ]
              },
              "identifier": {
                "use": "official",
                "value": "9f9fdefe-4c5e-456f-b419-4871645ebd01"
              },
              "status": "final",
              "type": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://loinc.org",
                    "code": "11503-0",
                    "display": "Medical records"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "subject": {
                "reference": "urn:uuid:75ad528e-2db7-47a6-90cd-3677b9c5c7e4",
                "display": "Agnieszka Øvrelid"
              },
              "date": "2021-01-18T16:18:22.4183485+00:00",
              "author": [
                {
                  "reference": "urn:uuid:a01b883a-752c-4b02-8b94-c175ff8602b3",
                  "display": "Bengt Fos Minde, HPR: 431002790"
                }
              ],
              "title": "Medication summary",
              "confidentiality": "N",
              "section": [
                {
                  "title": "Medication",
                  "code":
```

I want to add this element to the json body in the right place before doing another call:

```
 "relatesTo": [
            {
              "code": "replaces",
              "targetIdentifier": {
                "use": "official",
                "value": "57a9d650-ce21-42b2-a317-7d33a1eb4582"
              }
            }
          ]
```

The finished request body should be like this:

```
    {
  "resourceType": "Parameters",
  "parameter": [
    {
      "name": "medication",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Bundle",
        "id": "307a7183-06af-465e-b094-8514cdedf9f5",
        "meta": {
          "lastUpdated": "2020-11-06T07:44:28.6590617+00:00",
          "source": "http://base-fhir.qa.forskrivning.no/Patient/$getMedication",
          "profile": [
            "http://ehelse.no/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-MedicationBundle"
          ]
        },
        "type": "document",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-06T07:44:28.6590219+00:00",
        "total": 24,
        "link": [
          {
            "relation": "self",
            "url": "http://base-fhir.qa.forskrivning.no/Patient/$getMedication"
          }
        ],
        "entry": [
          {
            "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:160f33ca-29c6-4ff7-ad9d-366fb17ebe9a",
            "resource": {
              "resourceType": "Composition",
              "id": "cf61d45e-bae5-44e0-a64e-45f449958c3c",
              "meta": {
                "profile": [
                  "http://ehelse.no/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-MedicationComposition"
                ]
              },
              "identifier": {
                "use": "official",
                "value": "57a9d650-ce21-42b2-a317-7d33a1eb4582"
              },
              "status": "final",
              "type": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://loinc.org",
                    "code": "11503-0",
                    "display": "Medical records"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "subject": {
                "reference": "urn:uuid:09d55df4-b2db-45e2-a8b3-9891feef83ea",
                "display": "Agnieszka Øvrelid"
              },
              "date": "2020-11-06T07:44:28.6385246+00:00",
              "author": [
                {
                  "reference": "urn:uuid:a4e51226-ea04-4f41-b6b2-b7a1b287f990",
                  "display": "Selma Hadland, HPR: 2037661"
                }
              ],
              "title": "Medication summary",
              "confidentiality": "N",
              "relatesTo": [
                {
                  "code": "replaces",
                  "targetIdentifier": {
                    "use": "official",
                    "value": "57a9d650-ce21-42b2-a317-7d33a1eb4582"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "section": [
                {
                  "title": "Medication",
                  "code": {
                    "coding": [
                      {
                        "system": "http://ehelse.no/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-section-types",
                        "code": "sectionMedication",
                        "display": "List of Medication statements"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
```

How could I take the response and add an element in the session dynamically?

Comment: Try to make the example essential - as simple as possible - otherwise it is hard to get what the problem is. Add what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added a check like this to make the the response a map I can operate on.
.check(jsonPath("$..*").ofType[Map[String, Any]].saveAs("myJson"))
Now I want to add a json element i.e. relatesTo":[{"code": "replaces","targetIdentifier":{"use": "official","value": "3720076a-b74c-4781-af4b-9e3f567f8457"}}] to posistion x in the map, save it and use it in subsequent request

Answer (score 0):

Ok here two ideas:

- with Session:

  ```
  exec {
    callMyService
      .check(jsonPath("$..*").saveAs("myJson")) 
  }.exec { session =>
    val json = session("myJson").as[Map[String, Any]]
    val newJson = json.updated("relatesTo", Seq(Map("code" -> "replaces", ...)))
    // do something
    session
  }
  ```
- Or with transform:

  ```
  exec(
    callMyService
      .check(jsonPath("$..*").ofType[Map[String, Any]]
        .transform { json =>
          json.updated("relatesTo", Seq(Map("code" -> "replaces", ..)))
        }.saveAs("myJson")
      ))
  ```

However I could not test these ideas. Especially the data format of the part you want to add - I am not sure.

Comment: I am just curious how  json.updated("relatesTo", Seq(Map("code" -> "replaces", ..))) actually works. Does it say "replace "code" with "replaces". Thanks @pme